# Digitally Sign XML with SHA256

Tags: c#, vb.net, cryptography

I have an application written long before me that digitally signs an XML using the XmlDigSig specifications with SHA1 algorithm.

Now there was presented a demand to enable signing with SHA256 algorithm.
From reading online I've understood I'll need to implement a `SignatureDescription`, and than call `CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm()` to add it.

However, and unfortunately, `CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm()` is only availible starting from .NET 4.0, while I'm working with .NET 2.0 and there's no way to upgrade(There are literally 100,000s of customers that can not be all forced to upgrade).

Are there any suggestions for an alternative path?

I'd really prefer if that path still uses System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml, so that I don't have to rewrite the whole thing from scratch(It's not my code, and is a very poorly written framework for a poorly written application).

P.S.
You can post code in both C# or VB.NET, thanks.

Comment: Just in case you don't find a solution, our SecureBlackbox can do what you need (i.e. sign XML documents using SHA2).

Comment: Is there any reason the [standard SHA256 class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256.aspx) from the framework wouldn't help you?

Comment: I'm not simply creating a SHA256 hash, digital signature is longer procedure than simply creating a hash.

Comment: SHA-1 appears to be the only algorithm supported by the standard [XML Signature Syntax and Processing](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/). SHA-256 is in version 1.1 (dated March 2011), but its only a candidate at this point (http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/).